# convert XML with duplicated tags to JSON

Tags: python, json, xml

I need to convert this xml format into json list in Python.

```
<keywords>
<keyword number=\"1\">agr<\keyword>
<keyword number=\"2\">case<\keyword>
<keyword number=\"3\">coffee<\keyword>
<keyword number=\"4\">culture<\keyword>
<\keywords>
```

What I need:

```
{
    "keyword":['agr','case','coffee','culture']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<keywords>
<keyword number="1">agr</keyword>
<keyword number="2">case</keyword>
<keyword number="3">coffee</keyword>
<keyword number="4">culture</keyword>
</keywords>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = {'keyword': [e.text for e in root.findall('.//keyword')]}
print(data)
```

output

```
{'keyword': ['agr', 'case', 'coffee', 'culture']}
```